# suggest a database system to implement to c?

Tags: c, database

I need to create a program where I will be storing a bunch of data, not a whole lot but a lot of financial matter
I know my answer is all over google but some of those big database folks want to charge for distribution 
others only run online or on a virtual host

What is a good free database that I can embed with C and together store information locally and possibly online?

Or should I write my own?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ - That's a good architectural question for the sister site.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.sqlite.org/?

Comment: im sorry i was unaware of this site, i though maybe this was unappropiate for here, thanks for redirecting

Comment: sqlite or postgresql, depending on your requirements.

Comment: SQLite is the standard.

Comment: can postgresql run server-less?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "Shopping list" questions ("Please give me a list of links to consider") are not appropriate here. Google and Bing both specialize in searching for things and providing links to those search results. There are Meta posts [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/172661) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661) that explain the reasons. Voting to close as "not constructive". Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or should I write my own?

Don't waste time inventing your own database unless existing code doesn't do what you need.

> What is a good free database that I can embed with C and together store information locally and possibly online?

From your list of requirements, [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) should fit your needs just fine.

Comment: *Really* don't waste time inventing your own database. Particularly not for financials. [A good free database that you can embed with C](http://sqlite.org/mostdeployed.html) is pretty much a solved problem.